Intersection with object in Prettify helper type?
There's a pretty common typescript helper called Prettify:
type Prettify<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K];
} & {};

It is meant to get more helpful type displays in your IDEs and error messages. I never understood why there's an intersection with an object type at the end. Can someone explain? Why is it not just:
type Prettify<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K];
}


& unknown also works

It's hard to know exactly why someone else would write something without asking them directly, but... one reason why you might do this is to prevent TS from thinking you want to see "Prettify" in your types, as shown in the difference between the two versions at this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Hey @jcalz that really interesting and probably the reason for the {}! Thank you. Do you know why TS will show the Prettify type with there's no union with an object type? Are there any rules when we see the explicit type vs the name of the type that one could memorize?

I don't know all the rules, no. That also seems out of scope for the question as asked. I'll flesh my first comment out into a full answer, assuming you agree that it fully addresses the question.

TypeScript uses various heuristics to decide how to display a type via IntelliSense.  So when you write type F<T> = ⋯ and later use F<T> in a type, TypeScript might show F<T> as-is, or it might expand it out to its definition ⋯, and if that definition is itself a type alias, it might decide to leave it alone or expand that.  The exact rules for when and how this happens are obviously encoded in the compiler code, but not fully documented, and not guaranteed to stay the same in different versions of the language.  Occasionally some well-publicized change will be made, like the "smarter" type alias preservation released in TypeScript 4.2, but it will always effectively be the compiler's prerogative to decide between different representations of the same type.
In some sense, then, anything like Prettify<T> is going to try to tease some particular behavior out of a process which isn't guaranteed to cooperate.  If one version of Prettify<T> works for your use cases, then use it. But don't be surprised if that changes or breaks.

Anyway, it seems that if your type alias is a mapped type, the compiler tends to show the name and not its definition, in some circumstances. So you get this:
type Prettify<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

type Z = Array<Prettify<{ a: 0 }>>
// type Z = Prettify<{ a: 0; }>[]  

On the other hand, when the type alias is an intersection, it tends to expand to show the definition, and not the name... again, in some circumstances.  So you get this:
type Prettify<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
} & {};

type Z = Array<Prettify<{ a: 0 }>>
// type Z = { a: 0; }[]

So while the intersection of a non-nullish type with {} doesn't change it, (since {} is the "empty object type" and only excludes null and undefined, see How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?) it does affect the displayed type.
Playground link to code

Adding to @jcalz's answer, it seems that the extra intersection (& {}) is required only when Prettify is just simply a mapped type.
But, the problem gets resolved even if Prettify is wrapped in a conditional, in which case the extra intersection isn't required. You can find the original discussion here.
type Prettify<T> = T extends Function ? T : { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

type T1 = Prettify<Array<{ a: 1 }>>;
//   ^? type T1 = { a: 1; }[]

Playground link
And this sort of conditional is common with Prettify, because otherwise Prettify wouldn't be an identity on functions. Refer this PR.

A reference to TypeScript playground in case anyone is interested - https://tsplay.dev/WJPo5N. It consists of (1) conditional type + mapped type, (2) mapped types with NO intersection and (3) mapped types WITH intersection. Only second solution resolves Array<SimplePrettify<A>> as SimplePrettify<A>[]
